# How can I get all my values to be displayed on my table?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've tried changing the zero value in "e.push(addScore(e[0]))" to a 1 and basically it shows only the first four variables in the table. But when it is a zero, it shows the grade all as fail but list all the variable in the table. I want to be able to list all the variable and the correct grade class for each student.

```
var score = [
['Mary', 65],
['Jim', 70],
['Albert', 85],
['Carroll', 90],
['Francis', 50],
['Micheal', 62],
['John', 76],
['Tim', 88],
['Carlos', 64],
['Steven', 45]
],
 table = document.getElementById("table");

 function addScore(score) {
  let grade = '1'
  if (score >= 80) {
    grade = 'High Distinction';
  } else if (score >= 70 && score < 80) {
    grade = 'Distinction';
  } else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
    grade = 'Credit';
  } else if (score >= 50 && marks < 60) {
    grade = 'Pass';
  } else {
    grade = 'Fail';
  }
   return grade
  }
```

// iterating over the array
      score.forEach((e, i) => {
      var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

```
// adding score to each row
 e.push(addScore(e[0]))
 e.forEach((el, j) => {
 var cell = newRow.insertCell(j)
 cell.innerHTML = el
})
})


//this is for my inner html
<table id="table">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Score</th>
  <th>Grade</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Scores are second element in the array, so you should use index `1` instead of index `0`.

`e.push(addScore(e[1]));`

Also, there is a typo in your code.

```
else if (score >= 50 && marks < 60) {
    grade = 'Pass';
```

Replace `marks` in above statement with `score`.

This is the reason only four entries are displayed instead of all. Fifth value in the array (score of 50) is hitting this condition and throwing an `undefined` error.

**Live Example:**

```js
var score = [
    ['Mary', 65],
    ['Jim', 70],
    ['Albert', 85],
    ['Carroll', 90],
    ['Francis', 50],
    ['Micheal', 62],
    ['John', 76],
    ['Tim', 88],
    ['Carlos', 64],
    ['Steven', 45]
  ],
  table = document.getElementById("table");

function addScore(score) {
  
  if (score >= 80) {
    grade = 'High Distinction';
  } else if (score >= 70 && score < 80) {
    grade = 'Distinction';
  } else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
    grade = 'Credit';
  } else if (score >= 50 && score < 60) {
    grade = 'Pass';
  } else {
    grade = 'Fail';
  }
  return grade;
}

score.forEach((e, i) => {
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  // adding score to each row
  e.push(addScore(e[1]));
  
  e.forEach((el, j) => {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
    cell.innerHTML = el;
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```